# What is an intuitive interpretation for Kalman Gain as in Kalman filter?

Tags: time-series, kalman-filter

What know that the kalman gain converges to a steady state under certain realistic assumptions and can be used to derive the autocovariance function. Knowing these useful results, I cant help wondering what is an intuitive interpretation for Kalman Gain?

Comment: There ae many good answers for this in [this question on signal processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/how-to-understand-kalman-gain-intuitively).